# three servers serving same content, one Drupal database: implications for cron, etc

Tags: cron

We have an intranet with one primary, master server (let's call it #1) and two backups (#2 and #3), and I want users to be able to use any of them interchangeably. For our other applications, #1 is a MySQL master, the other two are slaves, but all the reads as well as the writes are done on #1 and it works just fine. Now I have a Drupal installation on #1. I copied all the files on #1 to #2 and #3, including the database settings, so all the sites access the database on #1, and it all appears to be working fine.

My question relates to cron. Any module that implements a cron hook can do anything it has permission to do, right? Both database and filesystem access. So how should I set up cron on servers 2 and 3? I discovered (by mindlessly coping my cron entry from #1 to #2 and #3) that you get an error when you try to run cron with cron already running (thankfully). So I've disabled it on #2 and #3 and started scratching my head. I need the filesystem cleanup but I don't need to try to re-run the database work.

So -- what's the best practice? Or is my whole setup ill-conceived?

Comment: I've always preferred a shared file system for things like this, you either set your file system up in an S3 bucket or set up a rsync command to sync the file system after any change is made by cron to servers #2 & #3. I've had to do it a couple of different ways in different situations but since you only have one database you have to do something like that to achieve this sort of setup. It's definitely not an ill conceived thought, some major sites that I've worked on have done the same thing with as many as 12 servers being load balanced at any given time :)

Comment: Bear with me -- I almost but not quite completely follow you. "...or set up a rsync command to sync the file system after any change is made by cron to servers #2 & #3." Do you mean, after cron runs on #2 or #3, run rysnc on #2 and #3 as in 

`rsync -az somebody@server1:/path/to/drupal/root/ /local/path/to/drupal/root/`

? Or the other way around?

And how should one schedule cron on #2 and #3 to avoid colliding with the task running on #1

Comment: Yea maybe I should have turned it into an answer (I will after this comment), but if you only have the main DB writes on #1 you should only have to run cron on #1 (if the others are slaves they essentially are just mirrors of #1) since #2/#3 should have that information after cron runs (meaning that cron runs on #1 the information in #2/#3 is updated from that). So now you have to ensure that the files folder is in sync also on #2/#3 b/c cron probably changed the /files folder in some way (by file cleanup or something) and the files from #1 should be synced with #2/#3 somehow.

Comment: Some of the larger sites I've worked on had the admin section behind a firewall/VPN so the main writes happen only in admin behind the VPN, files and all. Then on the front end to the end user they would be accessing a site that was running outside the firewall, so those db's were mirrored and only had read access (they never were bogged down by an admin doing their work, or cron running, or cache clearing and such) and the files were either a shared mount (this nfs), rysynced, or the files were kept in a S3 bucket and accessed over a CDN.

Comment: There are so many ways to do something like this, but you are definitely setting up something ill conceived in your thinking about this issue. I will try to put these comments into an answer with some pointers and things to check in just a bit.